# How to plot 3D contours on a 3D surface (built by patch) in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, 3d, patch, contour, geometry-surface

I just created a 3D surface in `MATLAB` using the code below :

```
p = patch ( 'Vertices' , XYZ , 'Faces' , F ) ;

set ( gca , 'CLim' , [-2000 1500] ) ;

set ( p , 'FaceColor' , 'interp' , 'FaceVertexCData' , V , 'EdgeColor' , 'none' , ...

... 'CDataMapping' , 'scaled' ) ;

axis 'equal'; 
axis 'tight';
set(gca, 'YDir','normal');
```

where `XYZ` is a `352x3` matrix containing coordinates of the points of the 3D surface.
`F` is a `700x3` matrix containing the faces which connect the points.
`V` is a `352x1` matrix containing the values on each of the 352 points of the 3D surface.

**Now this is the question : *How can I plot 3D contours on the surface !!?***

I've already tried `contour3` function, but it requires the input matrices to be of the different dimensions than now. ( I may need to use meshgrid, but unfortunately my XYZ points are irregularly distributed. However I'm not sure whether I can do this, since I'm using the patch function. )

Please help me on this.

Comment: Isn't there anyone to help !!!?

Answer (score 1):

Probably one possible solution is to perform the interpolation of your data to a regular mesh and then use `contour3` function. Check the manual for `TriScatteredInterp` function. Briefly, you should construct the interpolant first:

```
F = TriScatteredInterp(XYZ(:,1), XYZ(:,2), XYZ(:,3));
```

Then you have to evaluate the interpolant at regular locations `qx` and `qy` (obtained with `meshgrid`) and get corresponding values `qz`:

```
ti = 0:0.1:10;
[qx, qy] = meshgrid(ti, ti);  
qz = F(qx, qy);
```

Finally, you can use `contour3`:

```
contour3(qx, qy, qz, 30);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks miy. I'll try it. However, isn't there any solution for this patch !? I mean without changing the code !?

Comment: AFAIU you want both surface and contour on that surface, isn't it? Then you should plot surface with your code using `patch`, and then you can plot contour using the solution which I suggested (with `contour3` function).

Comment: I tried your suggested solution, but it didn't work as what I wanted to be. Any other solution !?

Comment: Actually I want the contours of V over XYZ ; ( not Z over XY ! ). What should I do now !?